# Unknow Accelerated mobile page url with 'amp-helper-frame.html/?appId='

Tags: onesignal, accelerated-mobile-page

I am getting traffic to unknown URL like `'www.xyz.com/amp-helper-frame.html/?appId='.` I don't know how this URL is getting triggered. Could not even find a source on web.

Comment: this is amp-onesignal issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

This is due to the missing 2 files that need to be added to amp onesignal. 
Here are the 2 files that need to be added to the root of your site
1) amp-helper-iframe.html
2) amp-permission-dialog.html

you can find the same in onesignal official documentation (point number 3).
Link: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/amp-web-push-setup#section-3-configure-the-amp-web-push-extension